# Undefined index: HTTP_X_URL_BEFORE_REWRITE

Tags: zend-framework, frameworks

I have the application which was written in Zend Framework. When I try to open the `index` file it give me an error:

> PHP Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_X_URL_BEFORE_REWRITE in
>   C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\test\library\Zend\Controller\Request\Http.php on
>   line 326 PHP Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_X_URL_BEFORE_REWRITE in
>   C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\test\library\Zend\Controller\Request\Http.php on
>   line 326

it`s depends of this line in index.php
    echo $ctrl->dispatch();
because when I coment it, application give me white site.

$ctrl is:

```
$ctrl = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$ctrl->setBaseUrl('/test');
$ctrl->throwExceptions(true);
$ctrl->registerPlugin(new DPCPluginAuth($auth, $acl));
$ctrl->setControllerDirectory($config->controllers->toArray());
echo $ctrl->dispatch();
```

and the function of liblary Zend is localized on Zend/Controller/Request/Http.php and name  public function setRequestUri

Please help me ... I don't know what's incorrect in that code and what means that message.

My mod_rewrite module is ISAPI_Rewrite3_Lite

Comment: Could you please write what is the question ? :-)

Comment: It was first post and I had problem with add some code :) Could you help me in my problem?

Comment: Hmm when I changed this line in the liblary from
    //$requestUri = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_URL_BEFORE_REWRITE']; 
to: 
    $requestUri = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL']; 
application works fine, but the url address is no hide like www.index.php. It looks like www.index.php\text\text1\text2. Mod_rewrite doesn`t work.